# How to fix my insertion sort code into ascending order? I am getting the wrong order as the output

Tags: java

```
public class InsertionSort{

public static void main(String [] args){

    int [] a = {45,23,4,6,2};

    for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
        for(int j = i; j>0; j--){

            if(a[j]< a[j-1]){

            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = temp; 

            System.out.println(a[j]);
            }

          }
      }
  }
}
```

output:

45
45
23
45
23
45
23
6
4

I would like it to be in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is already sorted, you just have to move the print statement out of the loops

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int [] a = {45,23,4,6,2};
    for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
        for(int j = i; j>0; j--){
            if(a[j]< a[j-1]){
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    // Arrays.stream(a).forEach(System.out::println); -- Java 8
   for (int idx = 0; idx < a.length; idx++) {
      System.out.println(a[idx]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to print the whole array after processing, not in the loop. Remove the print staement from the loop and put outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. However, there is an issue with the way you are printing the elements. Remember that your array is sorted only after the first for loop completes but you are printing `a[j]` during sorting process. At this point the elements are not at all sorted and thus you are getting wrong output. So you remove that print statement from the second for loop and use another for loop to print after sorting is over.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InsertionSort{

public static void main(String [] args){

    int [] a = {45,23,4,6,2};

    for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
        for(int j = i; j>0; j--){

            if(a[j]< a[j-1]){

            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = temp; 

           // System.out.println(a[j]);
            }

          }
      }
  //print array ascending order
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry..i am not refresh page and posted this answer..@Kartik